# How to Redirect from Android MainActivity to an already running Foreground service with full screen intent

Tags: android, kotlin, service, alarm, foreground

I am developing an Alarm application, when the alarm fires up it launches a full screen intent with foreground service.

If the user goes to home, then tries to open the app I want him to get redirected to the foreground service full screen intent.

The application is multi-module, The foreground service exists in scheduler module and I am trying to mutate the Main Activity in the UI.

I tried checking if the service is already running and then launch a startActivity with an intent to the foreground service using the main activity context. However, It throws the following exception

`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class`

Comment: "I want him to get redirected to the foreground service full screen intent" -- do you mean that you want the user to see the activity started by the full screen `Intent` associated with your foreground service's `Notification`? If so, start that activity using `startActivity()`.

Comment: I already tried this and received the exception mentioned in the post

Answer (score 0):

> then launch a startActivity with an intent to the foreground service

Replace that with a `startActivity()` call to the *activity that you want to show*. The `Intent` you pass to `startActivity()` needs to point to the *activity*. That is because you are trying to start an activity. The fact that this activity *also* happens to be used by a full-screen `Intent` for a foreground service `Notification` does not matter.